# How to send touch events to an android device as fast as possible using adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'd like to send touch events to an android device as fast as possible using `adb shell`
I already figured out I could do it like this:
`while true; do input tap 500 500; done;`
But this only taps like once every second.
I want to do it faster, as fast as possible.
is there any way to do this using `adb`?

Context:
There is this android game where tapping as fast as possible is one of the objectives. My thought was I could cheat this game by simulating the taps. Unfortunately the method I found is nowhere near as fast as I'd liked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it much faster. It doesn't use `adb` but it uses `monkeyrunner`, another tool that is also included in de Android SDK.

So I run `monkeyrunner` and do this:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
for i in range(1, 10000):
    device.touch(500, 500, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

Answer (score 2):

infinite loop
and replace `'DOWN_AND_UP'` to `MonkeyRunner.DOWN_AND_UP`

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
while True:
    device.touch(500, 500, MonkeyRunner.DOWN_AND_UP)
```